# How to configure "flatpak run org.gnome.meld" as git diff.tool and merge.tool

Tags: git, diff, flatpak, merge, meld

I can't use `meld` due to a messed up local installation of `cairo` or else. I've invested some time in it already including reporting the failure as a bug, but the maintainer states that it's not a bug which seems correct. Therefore I'd like to try a different more promising approach and use a `flatpak` installation. I can use `meld` as usual with `flatpak run org.gnome.meld`, the problem seems to be the argument passing.

A simple `git config --global diff.tool "flatpak run org.gnome.meld"` causes `git difftool` with uncommitted changes to fail due to

```
git config option diff.tool set to unknown tool: flatpak run org.gnome.meld
Resetting to default...

This message is displayed because 'diff.tool' is not configured.
See 'git difftool --tool-help' or 'git help config' for more details.
'git difftool' will now attempt to use one of the following tools:
meld opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff kompare gvimdiff diffuse diffmerge ecmerge p4merge araxis bc codecompare emerge vimdiff

Viewing (1/1): 'a'
Launch 'meld' [Y/n]?
```

In order to avoid trouble I created a script

```
#!/bin/sh
flatpak run org.gnome.meld "$@"
```

in `~/bin/` and made it executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/meld`. `~/bin/` is the first in my `PATH` and picked up according to `which meld`.

After the following scenario

```
> cd $(mktemp -d)
> git init .
Leeres Git-Repository in /tmp/tmp.2RFxjgBbQ5/.git/ initialisiert
> echo 1 > a
> git add a
> git commit -m "Initial commit"
[master (Basis-Commit) 997fe0d] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 a
> echo 2 > a
> git difftool

Viewing (1/1): 'a'
Launch 'meld' [Y/n]?
```

`meld` is launched to view `/tmp/cKSwbn_a` and `/home/[user]/a` (user obfuscated) which both don't exist.

I have other less comfortable workarounds at hand involving Docker, so I'm mostly interested in understanding how this approach could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Git configuration variable `diff.tool` only specifies the *name* of the diff tool used by default. The *command* to invoke is specified in `difftool.<tool>.cmd`. (See the [git-difftool(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) man page.)

As discussed [here](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1423) (with configuration examples), when invoking `flatpak run org.gnome.meld`, there are a couple of ways to give Meld access to paths under `/tmp` created by `git difftool`:

- Use the `--file-forwarding` option, to export the files into the document store. (Note: this will not export directories, so `git tool --dir-diff` will not work using this approach.)
- Use the `--filesystem=FS` option, to allow direct access to these files/directories.

Comment: `flatpak run --file-forwarding --filesystem=/tmp org.gnome.meld "$@"` works fine, thank you!